# PHP Check if row and session are empty

Tags: php

im trying to check if the row in table is empty and the session also in , can i know what im doing wrong here.

```
 if (empty($row['images']) && (!isset($_SESSION['picture']) || $_SESSION['picture'] == ''))
```

**EDIT :** 
posting the code as im trying to post some divisions based on the picture, and if there are no picture i post a demo.
i hope i explained it right.

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    do {
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if (empty($row['images']) && (!isset($_SESSION['picture']) || $_SESSION['picture'] == '')){
                    echo "<div>" ;
                    echo "                  <img src='images/logo.png' alt=""/>";
                    echo "                  <h1>This Is A Demo</h1>";
                    echo "                  <p>This is a Demo paragraph .</p>";
                    echo"                   <a href='../go_back.php'>Demo</a>";
                    echo "</div>" ;
                } else{
                    echo "<div>" ;
                    if(!empty($row['images'])) {
                        echo "                  <img src='images/users_iamge.png' alt=""/>";
                        echo "                  <h1>Not Demo</h1>";
                        echo "                  <p>This is Not Demo paragraph .</p>";
                    }else{ // fetch the session
                        echo "                  <img src='images/users_iamge.png' alt=""/>";
                        echo "                  <h1>Not Demo</h1>";
                        echo "                  <p>This is Not Demo paragraph .</p>";
                    }
                }       
                echo'<h1>' 
                echo'<p>'
                echo "</div>";                  
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }   
    } while (mysqli_more_result($conn));
}
```

Comment: Without more context we cannot help you. This *looks* ok.

Comment: i have no errors in error log, but this is a condition i added to the code and its not working, thank you for your validation

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve, @Mavia? context is missing... it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: we'll its proper syntax, we just don't know the business logic on this side

Comment: i have edited my question, and sorry for any lack of information

Answer (score 1):

Your logic appears to be wrong.
Recapping [basic operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in php.

The second condition in an `or` is only evaluated if the first condition evaluates to false.

Hence if `$_SESSION['picture']` is set, the evaluation of `$_SESSION['picture'] == ''` will never occur (as the first condition of the or evaluates to true).

To get the functionality you desire (truetable below)

```
Empty  | SEmpty  | SNull  | Result
-------+---------+--------+---------
  0        0         0        0
  0        0         1        0
  0        1         0        0
  0        1         0        0
  1        0         0        0
  1        0         1        1
  1        1         0        1
  1        1         1        1
```

You need:

```
if( empty($row['images']) && 
       ( (isset($_SESSION['picture']) && $_SESSION['picture'] == '') ||
         !isset($_SESSION['picture']) ) 
  )
```